# Need to convert List<String[]> To Dictionary<string, string[]>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a List<String[]> to Dictionary<string, string[]> but what I'm trying to do keeps either throwing errors or crashing. What is a valid solution?

```
List<String[]> logs = new List<String[]>();
foreach (string datum in data.Split('\n'))
{
    string[] cols = datum.Split(",");
    logs.Append(cols);
}
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = logs.ToDictionary(l => l[0], l => l.Skip(1).Take(4).All());
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> kvp in dict)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("k = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
InitializeComponent();
Debug.WriteLine("end");
```

What I have tried is above, specifically, the problem is the line:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = logs.ToDictionary(l => l[0], l => l.Skip(1).Take(4).All());
```

I have also tried it without .All()

Comment: When you use `.Take(...)` an `IEnumerable` is returned, but your contract is an array. Try removing `.All()` adding `.ToArray()` instead

Comment: _Scrap all of this_, get yourself a decent CSV Library, have it deserialize to a decent model and sleep like a baby.

Comment: What error message you get? Usually error message will tell you what issue you have

Comment: Could you please provide a sample input data and an expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I as can see, you have a `string data`, which you want to turn into dictionary; if you can guarantee that keys are unique:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = data
  .Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(line => line.Split(',', 6))
  .ToDictionary(items => items[0], 
                items => items.Skip(1).Take(4).ToArray());
```

**Edit:** If *duplicate* keys are possible, and you want to *group* values for these keys you can use `GroupBy` and then combine and flatten values with a help of `SelectMany`:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = data
  .Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))
  .GroupBy(items => items[0],      // 1st item is the key
           items => items.Skip(1)) // all the rest will be value
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
                group => group.SelectMany(item => item).ToArray());
```

Comment: It seems to be the most straightforward but I have another problem. I *do* have repeating keys, however, I would like to retain these values. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @bitcoinluvr6969: could you provide an example *in which way* do you want to retain the values. If you have lines like `A,1,2,3,4` and `A,5,6,7,8` what should be in the dictionary? `{A, {1, 2, 3. 4}}`? `{A, {5, 6, 7, 8}}`? `{A, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}}`? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I would like each unique key to have an array of all values for said key. This, in my mind, would wind up being List<String[]> for keys which collide.

Comment: @bitcoinluvr6969: so we can *group* all non-unique keys with a help of `GroupBy` and then combine all the values with `SelectMany`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `All()` with `ToArray()` to convert the IEnumerable returned by `Take(4)` to a `string[]`. Here is an updated version of the code that should work:

```
List<String[]> logs = new List<String[]>();

foreach (string datum in data.Split('\n'))
{
    string[] cols = datum.Split(",");
    logs. Append(cols);
}

Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = logs.ToDictionary(l => l[0], l => l.Skip(1).Take(4).ToArray());

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string[]> kvp in dict)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("k = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, string.Join(",", kvp.Value));
}
```

This should create a dictionary with the first element of each `String[]` in `logs` as the key and the next 4 elements as the value in a `string[]`. The updated `Debug.WriteLine` call will output the dictionary value as a comma-separated string to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are using `.Append()` method to add values to the list of `logs`?

From docs:
[Enumerable.Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=net-7.0)

> This method does not modify the elements of the collection. Instead,
> it creates a copy of the collection with the new element.

So if you replace `logs.Append(cols)` with `logs.Add(cols)` your original approach should produce result you expect.